# How to check if connection alive?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, connect, keep-alive

I use JDBC for connect to Oracle database. Application is running very long time. So I need if connection was not closed by server, not happened network disconnect etc.
Should I run small query or exists another way? Use isValid I cannot because this is not supported by jdbc driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running a simple query, something like

```
SELECT 1
  FROM dual
```

is the most foolproof approach.  That's what most Java EE app servers do to verify that a connection from their connection pool is still active.

Comment: Cannot be that if not answer from server query will run very long time?

Comment: @user710818 - In the vast majority of the cases, assuming the connection was successfully opened in the past, this will either immediately detect that the connection is broken or more or less immediately execute the query against the database.  If you issue a query immediately after your network loses its ability to route packets to the database server, it may take some time for the packets to time out.  But that is pretty rare and it's unlikely that anything else you might do would fail more quickly.