# Managing database connections in .NET - Keeping a connection alive

Tags: .net, sql-server, database-connection

I have a project which heavily relies on a database. Basically, every action in the project requires a query to the database.

The project follows the [Three-tier architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture), and at my Data layer I have an [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) instance as a data member for interacting with the database.

The problem is that sometimes the connection is being disconnected for no apparent reason.
My question is, how can I make sure the connection stays alive?
one suggestion I got so far is to send "[keep-alive-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355283/how-to-check-if-connection-alive)" periodically. something like `SELECT 1`.

I would also appreciate any insights you have about what may cause this periodical disconnection.

From [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258788/what-are-best-practices-on-managing-database-connections-in-net) I understand that keeping the connection as a data member might not be the best practice, but this is the current situation, and I would prefer to avoid changing it at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you could not keep the connection alive. It's not necessary in modern databases to do that. When you need to access the database, you should open a connection and as soon as you're done, close it.

Comment: What he said, plus: the database software will do a better job at optimizing the connection than you possibly could. Just let it do its job.